# Router.create in react-router v1.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the equivalent of Router.create (react-router v0.13) in react-router v1.0?

```
var router = Router.create({
  routes: routes,
  location: null // Router.HistoryLocation
});
```

I want to create a reference for the router to be used outside of the DOM.

```
router.transitionTo('app');
```

The code snippet above is the ones in v0.13. Wondering if anyone knows how to write them in react-router v1.0.

I have gone through the documentation of react-router, and I had found the [createRoutes](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createroutesroutes) function. I had no idea how to use it. Please help me on this.

Comment: Just to be clear - you're not using jsx in your project?

Comment: I am using webpack in my project.

Comment: Yes I know you're using webpack, but the reason I am asking is because the answer is different depending on whether you're using jsx in your project or not (this is a different question to if you are using webpack)

Comment: Yes, I am using jsx. Is it that much of a difference in this case? Mind sharing the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router as of v1.0 is now more modular than that. Things like navigation are functions of a "history" object rather than the router itself, which only handles routing.

To do the equivalent with React Router v1.0, you would instantiate the `history` object outside the router, then do whatever you want with it. There's more detailed documentation available at the guide for navigating outside of components: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md.

Answer (score 1):

In v1 Router is a component, the routes are children, and history is a prop:

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import { Router } from 'react-router'

<Router history={createHistory()}>{routes}</Router>
```

Edit: now I recommend you still install the history module, but import 'browserHistory' from react-router which provides a thin layer on top of it

In your top level component you can access [props.history.pushState(state, pathname, query)](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushstatestate-pathname-query) (further down you'll have to pass it through or use the mixin with createClass or something):

```
this.props.history.pushState(null, 'contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a [history](https://github.com/rackt/history) object for this in v1.0.0 - if you don't pass `Router` one, it will create one for you.

See [Getting Started](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#getting-started) for how to create a `history` object and [Navigation](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#navigation) for how to use it to perform navigation.