# React-route 1.0 equivalent of 0.13's Router.create

Tags: react-router

I've inherited a project that uses React-Router, and am uplifting all the dependencies, including react-router. However, its API has changed rather a bit between 0.13 and 1.0, and I was wondering how the following code could be translated to 1.0 form:

```
var routes = (
  <Route handler={...}>
    <Route name="..." path="/.../"
       handler={require('../pages/...jsx')}/>
    ...
  </Route>
);

[...snip...]

exports.generateStatic = function(url, cb) {
  var router = Router.create({
    routes: routes,
    location: url
  });

  router.run(function(Handler) {
    var pageHandler, html, title;
    var err = null;
    try {
      html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Handler/>);
      pageHandler = Page.handlerForPage(router, url);
      title = Page.titleForHandler(pageHandler);
    } catch (e) {
      err = e;
    }
    cb(err, html, { title: title });
  });
};
```

Rather than doing "actual navigation" this code is used to generate the app as static HTML by explicitly rendering all the routes in it, and the only questions I see on StackOverflow are for how to use what `Router.create` was for to do navigation ([Router.create in react-router v1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502013/router-create-in-react-router-v1-0-0)), which is not particularly relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is a bit different now - take a look at the server rendering docs for the current release: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.2/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md.

Comment: Hmm, that documentation still relies on there's being a server, which is not the case here: this is a server-less build tool that generates all the pages covered by the app, and writes them to disk as static content that can be loaded straight from file using a passove cli server, `public_html` hosting, etc.

Comment: It's the same thing though, no? You're still just generating the content in Node - you don't send it out on the response, but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: I missed the `match` being part of react-router. Yeah, you're right. Time to start rewriting the existing code to make use of this approach instead. Thanks.